# Error:(15, 1) Kotlin: A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')

Tags: kotlin

I get an error in this code:

```
fun num(num:Int):Int {
    if (num > 0){ 
        print(num % 10)
        return num / 10
    }
} //here an error
```

> Error:(15, 1) Kotlin: A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{…}')

What does it mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please also read this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Because you need to return something in the `else` half of your condition. Namely, if you didn't go into `if`, and didn't `return` anything yet.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the function body, an execution path is possible that contains no `return` statement, as the only `return` statement is placed inside the `if (...) { ... }` block. You don't return anything if the condition is not satifsfied.

A function with a declared value type (`fun num(num: Int): Int` in your case) should always return a value of that type, and when it has a block body, that should be done with `return` statements, one of which should always be reached.

You can fix that by adding another `return` statement after the `if` block:

```
fun num(num: Int): Int {
    if (num > 0) { 
        print(num % 10)
        return num / 10
    }
    return -1 // some default value
}
```

Comment: Don't forget 'if' is an expression, so you can have `return if` and not have the return in the 'if'. It's an acquired taste, especially if you've been coding Java for a very long time, but it's now my preferred.

Can then turn this into an expression body.

Answer (score 2):

Use function like below,

```
private fun validate(): Boolean {
    return when {
        TextUtils.isEmpty(binding.edtName.text) -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.please_enter_your_name), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            false
        }
        TextUtils.isEmpty(binding.edtEmail.text) -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.please_enter_your_email), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            false
        }
        else -> true
    }
}
```